# mysql output special charectors insted of arabic mysql new version

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

it was working fine on my old server, but when i shift it on new server, i am facing the probolem.

when i try to fetch Arabic data from the MySQL , i am getting these characters.
Ø§Ù„ØµÙØ­Ø© Ø§Ù„Ø±Ø¦ÙŠØ³ÙŠØ©

but when i write the Arabic content directly on my page it shows perfectly.

i already try these, but facing the same problem.

```
<?php @mysql_query("set global character_set_results=utf8");

@mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");

@mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8;");?>
```

[Screen Shot of my issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1Dep.jpg)

Comment: What's column type in the table I mean varchar or nvarchar?

Comment: column type = varchar

Comment: Make the column nvarchar and use the query.

Comment: even after update , i am facing the same problme.
i move my site from old server to new, on old server it was working fine,

Comment: Give a try with this query: SET NAMES utf8; See this link - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored ; see "Mojibake" in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your HTML.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

Comment: i alread try this
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Answer (score 0):

Your mysql settings seems ok. You can use this meta code like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Further check mysql column's character type. character set should be 'utf8'

I hope you already save php file without [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) right? If you aren't, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058849/php-how-to-create-a-file-encoded-as-utf-8-without-bom).

**EDIT:** 
**1.** Replace below line with your three line code:

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8'");
mysql_query("character_set_client = 'utf8'");
mysql_query("character_set_connection = 'utf8'");
mysql_query("character_set_database = 'utf8'");
```

**2.** Set document header:

```
header("content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

**like this way:**

```
<?php 
  // Send a raw HTTP header 
  header ('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); 

  // Declare encoding META tag, it causes browser to load the UTF-8 charset before displaying the page. 
  echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />'; 

  // Right to Left issue 
  echo '<body dir="rtl">'; 
?>
```

You can apply more option as your solution from [here](http://www.ar-php.org/faq-php-arabic.html). I hope my above explanation solved your issue.

Comment: my mysql column's character type is  "utf8_general_ci"

Comment: @MuhammadAlsahelsolutel: Check my EDIT.

Comment: no facing still same problem,

it was working fine on my old Linux server, now i move this to new server that is windows base. 

is there any issue of windows server.

Comment: Do _not_ use the deprecated `mysql_*` interface.