# json_encode() non utf-8 strings?

Tags: php, json, encoding, utf-8, ansi

So I have an array of strings, and all of the strings are using the system default **ANSI** encoding and were pulled from a SQL database. So there are 256 different possible character byte values (single byte encoding).
Is there a way I can get `json_encode()` to work and display these characters instead of having to use `utf8_encode()` on all of my strings and ending up with stuff like `\u0082`?

Or is that the standard for JSON?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Is there a way I can get json_encode() to work and display these characters instead of having to use utf8_encode() on all of my strings and ending up with stuff like "\u0082"?

If you have an ANSI encoded string, using `utf8_encode()` is the *wrong* function to deal with this. You need to properly convert it from ANSI to UTF-8 first. That will certainly reduce the number of Unicode escape sequences like `\u0082` from the json output, but technically these sequences [are valid for json](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), you must not fear them.

#### Converting ANSI to UTF-8 with PHP

[`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) works with `UTF-8` encoded strings *only*. If you need to create valid `json` successfully from an `ANSI` encoded string, you need to re-encode/convert it to `UTF-8` first. Then `json_encode` will just work as documented.

To convert an encoding from `ANSI` (more correctly I assume you have a `Windows-1252` encoded string, which is popular but wrongly referred to as `ANSI`) to `UTF-8` you can make use of the [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) function:

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8", "Windows-1252");
```

Another function in PHP that can convert the encoding / charset of a string is called [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) based on [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/). You can use it as well:

```
$str = iconv("CP1252", "UTF-8", $str);
```

#### Note on utf8_encode()

[`utf8_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) does only work for `Latin-1`, not for `ANSI`. So you will destroy part of your characters inside that string when you run it through that function.

---

Related: [What is ANSI format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format)

---

For a more fine-grained control of what `json_encode()` returns, see the [list of predifined constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) (PHP version dependent, incl. PHP 5.4, some constants remain undocumented and are available in the source code only so far).

### Changing the encoding of an array/iteratively (PDO comment)

As you wrote in a comment that you have problems to apply the function onto an array, here is some code example. It's *always* needed to *first* change the encoding before using `json_encode`. That's just a standard array operation, for the simpler case of `pdo::fetch()` a `foreach` iteration:

```
while($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  foreach($row as &$value)
  {
    $value = mb_convert_encoding($value, "UTF-8", "Windows-1252");
  }
  unset($value); # safety: remove reference
  $items[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row );
}
```

Comment: This pretty much answer my question. However when I do use the mb_convert_encoding() as you said, json_encode() is still just giving me null values for the strings that have odd characters in them. However if I do something like this, (also note this array with values is from a PDOStatement->fetchAll()). But for this method I found I'm iterating through each item rather than just grabbing an array and the characters show up escaped such as \u0082. etc.  "while($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { $items[] = array_map( utf8_encode, $row ); }"  should I be using this or doing it differently?

Comment: Actually, the mb_convert_encoding() does work. My mistake. Now it's down to looping through the array fetched from PDOStatement->fetchAll() or iterating through and fetching each item individually and using the code I put in my other comment. :\   (Each item in this array has a couple strings inside of it by the way)

Comment: @Josh, I've edited the question. I'm not sure if I totally understood your problem, I added an example how you can change the encoding of each element in the `$row` array you get from PDO.

Comment: I understand why this is the case, but /MAN/ this is annoying to have to deal with :D Thanks for the explanation @hakre

Answer (score 11):

The JSON standard **ENFORCES Unicode encoding**. From [RFC4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt):

```
3.  Encoding

   JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is
   UTF-8.

   Since the first two characters of a JSON text will always be ASCII
   characters [RFC0020], it is possible to determine whether an octet
   stream is UTF-8, UTF-16 (BE or LE), or UTF-32 (BE or LE) by looking
   at the pattern of nulls in the first four octets.

           00 00 00 xx  UTF-32BE
           00 xx 00 xx  UTF-16BE
           xx 00 00 00  UTF-32LE
           xx 00 xx 00  UTF-16LE
           xx xx xx xx  UTF-8
```

Therefore, on the strictest sense, ANSI encoded JSON wouldn't be valid JSON; this is why PHP enforces unicode encoding when using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode).

As for "default ANSI", I'm pretty sure that your strings are encoded in Windows-1252. It is incorrectly referred to as ANSI.

Comment: Yes, a string containing JSON encoded data must be a valid UTF-8 encoded string, but this doesn't mean the data itself cannot contain non-UTF-8 strings. The string `"\xff"` for example is a valid UTF-8 string (valid ASCII even), and represents a non-UTF-8 encoded string.

Answer (score 9):

```
<?php
$array = array('first word' => array('Слово','Кириллица'),'second word' => 'Кириллица','last word' => 'Кириллица');
echo json_encode($array);
/*
return {"first word":["\u0421\u043b\u043e\u0432\u043e","\u041a\u0438\u0440\u0438\u043b\u043b\u0438\u0446\u0430"],"second word":"\u041a\u0438\u0440\u0438\u043b\u043b\u0438\u0446\u0430","last word":"\u041a\u0438\u0440\u0438\u043b\u043b\u0438\u0446\u0430"}
*/
echo json_encode($array,256);
/*
return {"first word":["Слово","Кириллица"],"second word":"Кириллица","last word":"Кириллица"}
*/
?>
```

JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE (integer)
Encode multibyte Unicode characters literally (default is to escape as \uXXXX). Available since PHP 5.4.0.

http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-unescaped-unicode

Comment: For me this worked: json_encode($obj, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Answer (score -2):

I found the following answer for an analogous problem with a nested array not utf-8 encoded that i had to json encode:

```
$inputArray = array(
    'a'=>'First item - à',
    'c'=>'Third item - é'
);
$inputArray['b']= array (
          'a'=>'First subitem - ù',
          'b'=>'Second subitem - ì'
    );
 if (!function_exists('recursive_utf8')) {
  function recursive_utf8 ($data) {
     if (!is_array($data)) {
        return utf8_encode($data);
     }
     $result = array();
     foreach ($data as $index=>$item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
           $result[$index] = array();
           foreach($item as $key=>$value) {
              $result[$index][$key] = recursive_utf8($value);
           }
        }
        else if (is_object($item)) {
           $result[$index] = array();
           foreach(get_object_vars($item) as $key=>$value) {
              $result[$index][$key] = recursive_utf8($value);   
           }
        } 
        else {
           $result[$index] = recursive_utf8($item);
        }
     }
     return $result; 
   }
}
$outputArray =  json_encode(array_map('recursive_utf8', $inputArray ));
```

Answer (score -3):

```
json_encode($str,JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_APOS|JSON_HEX_QUOT);
```

that will convert  windows based ANSI to utf-8 and the error will be no more.

Comment: none of those flags have anything to do with encoding
JSON_HEX_TAG: deals with "<" and ">";
JSON_HEX_AMP: deals with "&";
JSON_HEX_APOS: deals with single-quote "'";
JSON_HEX_QUOT: deals with double quote'"';

Answer (score -4):

Use this instead:

```
<?php 
//$return_arr = the array of data to json encode 
//$out = the output of the function 
//don't forget to escape the data before use it! 

$out = '["' . implode('","', $return_arr) . '"]'; 
?>
```

Copy from [json_encode php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)'s comments. Always read the comments. They are useful.

Comment: That's not helpful because it doesn't deal with the encoding at all.