# Upside down quote “ json encoding returns null - PHP

Tags: php, prepared-statement, json

I have a prepared statement written on PHP that retrieves a string from MySQL, then i use
json_encode to send the data to client, and it works perfect.

The problem happens when the string in MySQL contains “ .

Should i encode it differently? Or use some special flags?Or there are other solutions?

Thanks

Comment: It encodes fine for me when entered from the CLI (to \u201c). What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: null returned from where? can you be more specific, maybe with some code?

Answer (score 1):

> Should i encode it differently?

I'd say yes. Obviously the string you receive from the database is not UTF-8 encoded. And that's the problem, because [`json_encode`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/json_encode) needs UTF-8 encoded strings. If they are invalid, it will return `NULL` - because there was no valid data to encode.

You can verify this by checking for the last error with the [`json_last_error`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/json_last_error) function.

So when you query data from your database, tell the database server that you expect UTF-8 encoded data by setting the database client encoding. Consult the documentation of the database client library you're using, it's documented there.

See as well **[json_encode() non utf-8 strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6606713/367456)** which shows how you can re-encode the strings itself if you don't want to change the database client connection.