# How to use PHP json_encode without UTF8?

Tags: php, json, unicode, utf-8

I am working on an old existing website. All pages were encoded in ISO-European, including the MySQL database.

I want to add some AJAX using PHP's json_encode, which only supports UTF8.

Is there a solution to use json_encode without UTF8?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606713/json-encode-non-utf-8-strings, does this help?

Comment: just to clear up a point: JSON requires/is-specified only for unicode standard (where utf-8 is a specific encoding that fits). So the statement `use json_encode without UTF8` makes no real sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is to convert your data to UTF-8 before passing it to `json_encode`. That function requires UTF-8 data, and unless you want to reimplement `json_encode` yourself it's a lot easier to go along with its requirements:

```
function recursivelyConvertToUTF8($data, $from = 'ISO-8859-1') {
    if (!is_array($data)) {
        return iconv($from, 'UTF-8', $data);
    }
    return array_map(function ($value) use ($from) {
        return recursivelyConvertToUTF8($value, $from);
    }, $data);
}

echo json_encode(recursivelyConvertToUTF8($myData));
```

This is not necessarily a complete solution covering every possible use case, but it should illustrate the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php), [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) and `eval` to convert an array to UTF-8 recursively. It's a bit of a hack, but something like the following works:

```
$obj = array("key" => "\xC4rger"); // "Ärger" in Latin1
eval('$utf8_obj = ' . utf8_encode(var_export($obj, TRUE)) . ';');
print json_encode($utf8_obj);
```

This will print

```
{"key":"\u00c4rger"}
```

Comment: There's gotta be a saner way to do that besides `eval`...!