# php json_encode bug patch

Tags: php, json

i have data in text file which i load to array rows wise , but recently i have noticed that when "µ" come in data then json_encode retrun blank response ,and when i remove "µ" from data then json_encode function work

i have php version 5.5.3

```
$dat = array("0"=>"hello","1"=>"world");
echo json_encode($dat);   // work

$data = array("0"=>"hello","1"=>"180.00 10µH");
echo json_encode($data);  // blank response ..
```

i searched for json_enocde function on github php page , but its all in C ,

so any idea how to patch this function

Comment: Oh..... You are right.

Comment: Try the option 'JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR'

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6606713/json-encode-non-utf-8-strings

Comment: Just tossing this out there, from the [`json_encode()` documentation page](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php): *"All string data must be UTF-8 encoded."* That being said, the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` bitmask option sounds promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
function utf8_converter($array) {
    array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key) {
        if (!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)) {
            $item = utf8_encode($item);
        }
    });

    return $array;
}

$data = array("0"=>"hello","1"=>"180.00 10µH");
$data = utf8_converter($data);
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR);
```

Comment: Your code output: `["hello","180.00 10\u00b5H"]`. Notice the `µ` converted to respective special characters(`\u00b5`).

Comment: @BhavikShah yes, right. It will do it. But whenever you are converting it back using json_decode it will come back to it's origin form. So don't worry about it.

Comment: am getting error utf8_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in line#

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dat = array("0"=>"hello","1"=>"world");
echo json_encode($dat);   // work

$data = array("0"=>"hello","1"=>"180.00 10µH");
echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Example: https://ideone.com/cYDf8Y

Comment: am getting blank response , maybe because my final big array is multidimensional