# Python Regex for greek words

Tags: python, regex, unicode, python-unicode

I want to make a python script that uses a regular expression to filter the lines that have certain greek words out of a source text which I provided and then write those lines to 3 different files depending on the words encountered.

Here is my code so far:

```
import regex

source=open('source.txt', 'r')
oti=open('results_oti.txt', 'w')
tis=open('results_tis.txt', 'w')
ton=open('results_ton.txt', 'w')

regex_oti='^.*\b(ότι|ό,τι)\b.*$'
regex_tis='^.*\b(της|τις)\b.*$'
regex_ton='^.*\b(τον|των)\b.*$'

for line in source.readlines():
    if regex.match(regex_oti, line):
        oti.write(line)
    if regex.match(regex_tis, line):
        tis.write(line)
    if regex.match(regex_ton, line):
        ton.write(line)
source.close()
oti.close()
tis.close()
ton.close()
quit()
```

The words that I check for are `ότι | ό,τι | της | τις | τον | των`.

The problem is that those 3 regular expressions (`regex_oti`, `regex_tis`, `regex_ton`) do not match anything so the 3 text files I created do not contain anything.

Maybe its an encoding problem (Unicode)?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Python 2.7.3 actually :)

Comment: You have to use raw unicode strings in regexp along with re.U flag in order to make it work.

Comment: @alko: the `re.U` flag is implied when using a `unicode` string value for the regular expression.

Comment: Tongue-in-cheek answer - use Python 3.x to avoid problems with unicode problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to match encoded values, as bytes, with a regular expression that *most likely* won't match unless your Python source encoding exactly matches that of the input files, and then only if you are not using a multi-byte encoding such as UTF-8.

You need to decode the input files to Unicode values, and use a Unicode regular expression. This means you need to *know* the codecs used for the input files. It's easiest to use [`io.open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) to handle decoding and encoding:

```
import io
import re

regex_oti = re.compile(ur'^.*\b(ότι|ό,τι)\b.*$')
regex_tis = re.compile(ur'^.*\b(της|τις)\b.*$')
regex_ton = re.compile(ur'^.*\b(τον|των)\b.*$')

with io.open('source.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as source, \
     io.open('results_oti.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as oti, \
     io.open('results_tis.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as tis, \
     io.open('results_ton.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as ton:

    for line in source:
        if regex_oti.match(line):
            oti.write(line)
        if regex_tis.match(line):
            tis.write(line)
        if regex_ton.match(line):
            ton.write(line)
```

Note the `ur'...'` raw unicode strings to define the regular expression patterns; now these are Unicode patterns and match *codepoints*, not bytes.

The `io.open()` call makes sure you read `unicode`, and when you write `unicode` values to the the output files the data is automatically encoded to UTF-8. I picked UTF-8 for the input file as well, but you need to check what the correct codec is for that file and stick to that.

I've used a `with` statement here to have the files close automatically, used `source` as an iterable (no need to read all lines into memory in one go), and pre-compiled the regular expressions.

Comment: i dont think this will work... it throws me an error that says:
UnicodeDecodeError:'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 4: invalid continuation byte
my source file has generally many symbols and stuff... here is the first line of it :
CON[Και<C*και>] VP[έχουν<Vmip3p-ia-*έχω> περάσει<Vmn----pa-*περνω>] NP[*πολλοί<A0pmpn*πολύς>] CON[και<C*και>] NP[*&laquo;<F> χαρισματικοί<A0pmpn*χαρισματικός> *&raquo;<F> *.<F>] #

dont bother checking it out it is meant for specific use of machine learning...

Comment: Then your input is not UTF8. Pick the right codec for the file.

Comment: How do i know which codec is right? Sry for the trouble ... i am new to all this :)
And something else, does the encoding of the source file and the output files (the 3 of em) has to be the same ?

Comment: No, the output encoding can be different. Sometimes, working out the *input* codec requires trial and error. What codec are you using when viewing the file?

Comment: "ANSI" is [Windows codepage 1252](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format); use `'cp1252'` in Python. Or, at least, that is what it *usually* means. In the console, run `chcp`, it'll print the current codepage. If it says `1253` (Greek codepage) then use `cp1253` obviously.

Comment: HA ! Finally figured it out... Turns out i had to use encoding "Windows-1253" .... u never know where u get stuck with some things :D :D
kudos to you mate @Martijn Pieters