# How to write and read printable ASCII characters to/from UTF-8 encoding file?

Tags: r, file-io, utf-8, ascii, file-encodings

I want to write to a file with UTF-8 encoding containing the character 
 `10001100` which is `Œ` the Latin capital ligature OE in extended ASCII table,

```
zz <- file("c:/testbin", "wb")
writeBin("10001100",zz)
close(zz)
```

When I open the file with office(encoding=utf-8), I can see `Œ` what I can not read is with readBin?

```
zz <- file("c:/testbin", "rb")
readBin(zz,raw())->x
x
[1] c5
readBin(zz,character())->x
Warning message:
In readBin(zz, character()) :
incomplete string at end of file has been discarded
x
character(0)
```

Comment: I get `8c` from `charToRaw`, can you put the output of `sessionInfo()` into your question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are multiple difficulties here.

- **Firstly, there are actually [several "Extended ASCII" tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII).** Since you are on Windows you are probably using [CP1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) which is one of them, also called `Windows-1252` or [`ANSI`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format), and the Win default "latin" encoding. However [the code for `Œ` varies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%92#Encodings) within this family of tables. In `CP1252`, `"Œ"` is represented by `10001100` or `"\x8c"`, as you wrote. However it [does not exist in `ISO-8859-1`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1). And in `UTF-8` it corresponds to `"\xc5\x92"` or `"\u0152"`, as rlegendi indicated.

So, to write `UTF-8` from `CP1252`-as-binary-as-string, you have to convert your string into it a "raw" number (the R class for bytes) and then a character, change its "encoding" from `CP1252` to `UTF-8` (in fact convert its byte value to the corresponding one for the same character in `UTF-8`), after that you can re-convert it to raw, and finally write to the file:

```
char_bin_str <- '10001100'
char_u <- iconv(rawToChar(as.raw(strtoi(char_bin_str, base=2))),
              # "\x8c"    8c     140    '10001100'
                from="CP1252",
                to="UTF-8")

test.file <- "~/test-unicode-bytes.txt"

zz <- file(test.file, 'wb')
writeBin(charToRaw(char_u), zz)
close(zz)
```

- **Secondly, when you `readBin()`, do not forget to give a number of bytes to read which is big enough (`n=file.info(test.file)$size` here), otherwise it reads only the first byte (see below):**

  zz <- file(test.file, 'rb')
  x <- readBin(zz, 'raw', n=file.info(test.file)$size)
  close(zz)

  > x
  >   [1] c5 92
- **Thirdly, if in the end you want to turn it back into a character, correctly understood and displayed by R, you have first to convert it into a string with `rawToChar()`. Now, the way it will be displayed depends on your default encoding, see `Sys.getlocale()`** to see what it is (probably something ending with `1252` on Windows). The best is probably to specify that your character should be read as `UTF-8` – otherwise it will be understood with your default encoding.

  xx <- rawToChar(x)
  Encoding(xx) <- "UTF-8"

  > xx
  >   [1] "Œ"

This should keep things under control, write the correct bytes in `UTF-8`, and be the same on every OS. Hope it helps.

---

**PS**: I am not exactly sure why in your code `x` returned `c5`, and I guess it would have returned `c5 92` if you had set `n=2` (or more) as a parameter to `readBin()`. On my machine (*Mac OS X 10.7, R 3.0.2* and *Win XP, R 2.15*) it returns `31`, the hex ASCII representation of `'1'` (the first char in `'10001100'`, which makes sense), with your code. Maybe you opened your file in Office as `CP1252` and saved it as `UTF-8` there, before coming back to R?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead (I replaced the binary value with the UTF encoding because I think it is better when you want such an output):

```
writeBin(charToRaw("\u0152"), zz)
```

Comment: why charToRaw("Œ") is c5 92 not `8c` ?

Comment: How did you got `8c` there? :-)

Comment: in the ascii table ,you can see it.

Comment: Hm, I don't know which table you use, can you give me a link? According to this document, this should be `92` not `8c` as an UTF-8 encoded character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0152/charset_support.htm The sequence `c58c` is letter O with macron http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/014c/index.htm