# Two word with the same representation in UTF-8 have different representation in ASCII

Tags: utf-8, python-imaging-library, ansi, farsi

I have a Farsi word that if shown in UTF-8 coding is like this:

```
"خطاب"
```

I have two versions of this word, both in Notepad++ in UTF-8 are shown as above.
But if I look at them in ANSI mode then I see:

```
ïºïºŽï»„ïº§
```

and for the other one I see:

```
Ø®Ø·Ø§Ø¨
```

How come the same words have such a different representation in ANSI format? When I use PIL in Python to draw these, the result is correct for one of these and not correct for the other.

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: It [depends on your system settings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/701920/847349). ANSI might not include the Farsi code page

Comment: If you are interpreting a UTF-8 encoded file in an ANSI encoding, of course you'll see garbage characters. It's not about them "having different representations", it's about interpreting a file in an incorrect encoding. See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: @deceze thank you very much for the link, I will read it for sure. However, even in ANSI encoding I should see garbage, shouldn't both of them show the same garbage?

Comment: See Mojibake in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 2):

In Unicode you can represent some character in more than one way.
In this case, these Arabic characters are represented with code points from the [Arabic Presentation Forms-B Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_Presentation_Forms-B) in the first case, and with code points from the regular [Arabic Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_%28Unicode_block%29) in the second case.

If you convert the text

> ïºïºŽï»„ïº§

to a byte stream, you get

> EFBA[**0F**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_in) EFBA8E EFBB84 EFBAA7

Notice that you are not seeing a character representing the `0F` byte in the text above, because it's a non-visual character.

Now that byte stream is representing a UTF-8-encoded text. Decoding it will give you the following Unicode code points:

> FE8F FE8E FEC4 FEA7

You can match those in the [Arabic Presentation Forms-B Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_Presentation_Forms-B) to form your Farsi text:

> خطاب

You can do the same process for the other text: `Ø®Ø·Ø§Ø¨` gives you the byte stream `D8AE D8B7 D8A7 D8A8`, which represents UTF-8-encoded text, which decoded gives you the Unicode code points `062e 0637 0627 0628`, which matched to the regular [Arabic Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_%28Unicode_block%29) gives you again the text `خطاب`.