# How can I set encoding to ANSI in PhpStorm?

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I'm working in an environment where I'm the only one using PhpStorm. The rest of my coworkers are using PhpDesigner and in that IDE, they are using "File Encoding: ANSI" which I don't seem to find in PhpStorm.

How do I set the file encoding to ANSI in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ANSI can refer to one of several different character sets see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format) for details. Assuming that you are working on US or Western European this should correspond to the windows 1252 character set, which you can set in the File>Settings>File Encoding panel. You can set the default encoding for the IDE as well as special cases for individual projects, directories and files. This information is valid for version 5 of PhpStorm but I expect that this particular settings option will be similar across the different versions.

With newer version of phpstorm, you will find the file encoding in File>Settings>Editor>File Encodings