# Unable to convert special characters in UTF-8 file into ANSI

Tags: c#, utf-8, ansi

I have a file that needs to be read and a text has to be added at the end.
The program failed due to character "í" .
On opening the file in notepad++ (UTF-8) encoding, I could see [image]

In my C# code I tried to convert it to Default encoding, but the application changes it to "?" instead of "í".

Sample code:

```
string processFilePath = @"D:\Test\File1.txt";
string outfile = @"D:\Test\File2.txt";

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(processFilePath))
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outfile, false, Encoding.Default))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

I looked into similar questions on SO (above code snipped was the modified version from here):
[UTF-8 to ANSI Conversion using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22359662/utf-8-to-ansi-conversion-using-c-sharp)

I tried different types of encoding available in the "System.Text.Encoding" - ASCII/ UTF*/ Default but the best I could get is a "?" instead of "í".

I had also gone through : http://kunststube.net/encoding/ , I did learn a lot, but was still unable to resolve the issue.

What I am getting: [image]

What I need: [image]

[On Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.6.1): [image]

What else am I missing (Should have been easy if System.Text.Encoding.ANSI existed )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.8):

> StreamReader defaults to UTF-8 encoding unless specified otherwise,
>   instead of defaulting to the ANSI code page for the current system.

i.e. when opening `StreamReader(processFilePath)` it takes data as in UTF-8, which seems not the case, i.e. if the source text is ANSI, or most likely Windows-1252 for Spanish, use

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(processFilePath, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)))
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outfile, false, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Note specified 1252 and UTF8.

P.S. Also note that *false* in StreamWriter will not append to the end, [but overwrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Text_Encoding_).

Comment: Thanks a lot @user2316116 this solution worked!!!
Yes, I'll use 'true' for appending the text.