# How to convert a string UTF-8 to ANSI in java?

Tags: java, string, utf-8, ansi

I have a string in UTF-8 format. I want to convert it to clean ANSI format. How to do that?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "ANSI"? There are various encodings which could be (inaccurately) referred to as "ANSI". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format

Answer (score 3):

You could use a java function like this one here to convert from UTF-8 to ISO_8859_1 (which seems to be a subset of ANSI):

```
private static String convertFromUtf8ToIso(String s1) {
    if(s1 == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String s = new String(s1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    byte[] b = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    return new String(b, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
}
```

Here is a simple test:

```
String s1 = "your utf8 stringáçﬠ";
String res = convertFromUtf8ToIso(s1);
System.out.println(res);
```

This prints out:

```
your utf8 stringáç?
```

The *ﬠ* character gets lost because it cannot be represented with ISO_8859_1 (it has 3 bytes when encoded in UTF-8). ISO_8859_1 can represent *á* and *ç*.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
new String("your utf8 string".getBytes(Charset.forName("utf-8")));
```

in this format 4 bytes of `UTF8` converts to 8 bytes of `ANSI`

Answer (score 0):

Converting UTF-8 to ANSI is not possible generally, because ANSI only has 128 characters (7 bits) and UTF-8 has up to 4 bytes. That's like converting long to int, you lose information in most cases.