# C File Handling and end of the line character in Notepad

Tags: c, file-io, newline, eof

I was reading C File Handling and I ran into **fseek()** function. The following statement was written in the book, regarding the use of it:

```
int fseek(FILE *stream, long offset, int from );  //The function prototype
```

"On binary streams, seeks from **SEEK_END** may not be supported an should therefore be avoided. On text streams, the **offset** must be zero if **from** is either **SEEK_CUR** or **SEEK_END**. The offset must be a value previously returned from a call to to **ftell()** on the same stream if **from** is **SEEK_SET**."

I don't understand the given usage.Why the offset should be zero ?

To find the answer, I investigated and I found out that, in text streams, there is mapping of EOL(newline) from C program to different character in MSDOS. The size of *newline* character in C is 1 byte.
 What happens when it gets written to a Notepad file?. What is the size of EOL in notepad?
I created a notepad file and did the following:

**Scenario 1:**
abcd

The size shown was 4 bytes. Where is newline or EOF now?

**Scenario 2:**
abcd
a

The size shown was 7 bytes.

**Scenario 3:**
abcd
a
b

The size shown was 10 bytes. How was the size calculated now?

Can anybody answer these questions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: Notepad uses CR LF characters as new line and all microsoft products do so thus new line would use 2 bytes.

Comment: And can anyone explain my first question regarding fseek() usage?

Answer (score 1):

I assume `notepad` adds windows like end of line which consists of `\r\n` hence the answer to your question is `2`, and that obviously explains the observed behavior.

Also, `EOF` is not a character written to the file, it's a special value returned by some funcitions to indicate the end of the file.

Comment: So you are saying size of EOL in notepad is 2 bytes?

Comment: How do you explain the scenario 2? And EOF doesn't get written, then How does Notepad reads the end of the file?

Comment: @pulp_fiction not "in notepad" but in text files in Windows encoding.

Comment: "Windows encoding" huh? When I save the document, it shows me ANSI encoding. Is it not the same as being followed in the C program?

Comment: @pulp_fiction [it's another name for Windows encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format).

Comment: Also, `EOF` is not written to the file by `notepad` you can write it if you want, but it will not mark the end of the file, it will be just data written to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad uses DOS / Windows sequence of `\r\n` to mark end-of-line.

- First example has no end-of-line sequence, so 4 printable characters produce size of 4: `a b c d`
- Second example has one end-of-line sequence, so 5 printable characters plus 2 for the end-of-line marker make its size 7: `a b c d \r \n a`
- Third example has two end-of-line sequences, so 6 printable + 4 for two end-of-line markers make its size 10: `a b c d \r \n a \r \n b`

You can write a small C program to read your files character-by-character, and print them as numbers. `\r`'s code is 13; `\n`'s code is 10.

> Where is the `EOF` character? Is it not counted in for size calculation?

`EOF` is not a character, it is a value returned by I/O functions to indicate that the end of input has been reached. It has a special numeric value which is different from numeric values of all other characters. In fact, the reason the functions from `getchar` family return `int`, not `char`, is to accommodate returning `EOF` marker, instead of reserving one of the character codes for it.

Comment: Where is the EOF character? Is it not counted in for size calculation?

Comment: Can you tell, who "catches" the EOF value?

Comment: @pulp_fiction I/O functions of your environment (usually, OS-related, but could be something else in embedded systems) "know" the length of file in characters, so after the last character has been read, they return `EOF` value every time your program requests the next character. Console input behaves in a similar way, except console reserves a special key sequence to signal the end of input manually (`Ctrl+D` on UNIX, `Ctrl+Z` on Windows).

Comment: Okay, Correct me if I am wrong, "the OS I/O functions return the EOF, which in turn is returned by C library I/O functions to indicate the end of file."

Comment: @pulp_fiction That's a system-dependent detail of implementation. It can be done like this, but it's also possible for OS I/O functions not to return anything, expecting the C library to keep track of file size (which OS I/O functions provide) and return `EOF` once their internal marker reaches the file size. I/O functions in C library provide an abstraction layer on top of OS I/O functions, hiding these details from you.