# Parsing Georgian characters with BeautifulSoup in Python (encoding issue)

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup in Python 2.7 to parse HTML tables content from HTML files. The script should grab a number of input HTML files (notepad++ says they are UTF-8 w/o BOM) find the first table in file and print the rows and columns into another .html or .txt file in some human readable form (one output file for one input file).

That data in rows and columns is a bunch of Georgian alphabet characters and there is a problem with encoding I guess.

BeautifulSoap says that default output encoding is UTF-8, but it doesn't seem to be true in my case. Notepad++ is showing ANSI and characters don't display correctly.

My code is as following:

```
def get_flexion(number_of_files):

    # interates through all input files
    for i in range(1, number_of_files):
        input = open('html/' + str(i) + '.html')

        # parsing html
        soup = BeautifulSoup(input, from_encoding='utf-8')
        table = soup.find('table')
        print table
        if (table == None):
            continue
        else:
            rows = table.find_all('tr')

            # creating output file
            output = open('output/' + str(i) + '.html', 'wb')

            # getting table data
            for tr in rows:
                columns = tr.find_all('td')
                for td in columns:
                    text = td.find(text=True)
                    if text != None:
                        output.writelines(text)
                output.writelines('\n')
```

As you can see I add a parameter at the beggining of the parsing which should force UTF-8. I tried various other ways taking examples from documentation but my output file still seems to be ANSI. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Under Python2.x, the builtin `open` function will open a file with the operating system's default character encoding. For Windows, this is e.g.  Windows-1252 on most Western systems, which gets the [misnomer "ANSI"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/701920/2476444) in several programs.

Because of that default for `open`, any time you write to the file, the contents are being encoded using that codepage. From your description, that codepage on your system does not support the Georgian characters (even though the characters found can all be mapped, which is lucky coincidence) and that is not what you want: you want it encoded using an encoding that supports Georgian characters, like `utf-8`. To do that, you could use

```
import codecs
outputfile = codecs.open(path, mode, encoding='utf-8')
```

and continue writing to your `outputfile` as usual.

Note that this is only relevant for Python2.x. Starting with Python3.3, the default source encoding became utf-8. It was the topic of [PEP3120](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/). The builtin `open` of Python3.3 has an `encoding` argument, which you can specify directly ("explicit is better than implicit").