# What's an ansi class in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

I started using reflection in my project.

When I create a type and I want to specify the TypeAttributes, I have two options:
`AnsiClass` and `Class`. They are both set to 0 in the enum `TypeAttributes`.

```
public enum TypeAttributes
{
    //     LPTSTR is interpreted as ANSI.
    AnsiClass = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Specifies that the type is a class.
    Class = 0,
...
```

1- What's an `ANSI Class` (I noticed that, it's related to the `LPTSTR`, but I didn't  understood well enough)?

2- What's the difference between an `AnsiClass` and a `Class` when I use `Reflection`.

**EDIT**

Here's an example of specifying the TypeAttributes in Reflection:

```
TypeBuilder typeBuilder = mbuilder.DefineType("DataRow", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.AnsiClass | TypeAttributes.Class);
```

Comment: Can you show some relevant code? MSDN links perhaps? It [seems](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/typeattributes.cs,ada9a877a9d95037,references) to have to do with string marshaling during interop though.

Comment: Whenever you have questions like this, the MSDN documentation is a great resource. `TypeAttributes` on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeattributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Related documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeattributes(v=vs.110).aspx The remarks indicates that the ansi part is regarding string formats (encodings).

Comment: Okay, so great minds think alike... ;) Perhaps a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format ?

Comment: See also [Default Marshaling for Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @SimonSvensson I was reading the MSDN documentation before (and now that other SO question).  The MSDN documentation tells me what the  Type Attribute _is_, but doesn't really tell me what it is _for_

Comment: The msdn doc has the same information as the one in the TypeAttributes enum. It's useless.

Comment: You know it better as StructLayoutAttribute.CharSet.  Every .NET type has it, even if you don't use the attribute explicitly.  Ecma-335 is a good source for this kind of info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have two options: AnsiClass and Class

No, those are orthogonal.  `AnsiClass` tells the marshaller that all string properties are to be marshalled as ANSI strings.  The other options in that category are:

```
UnicodeClass
AutoClass
CustomFormatClass
```

`Class` indicates that they type is, well, a `class`.  The only other option in that group is `Interface`.  Interestingly, when you look at the attributes of framework types, classes, structs, and interfaces all have the `Class` attribute, so I'm not sure what it's used for.

```
 typeof(object).Attributes.Dump();   
 typeof(int).Attributes.Dump();   
 typeof(ICloneable).Attributes.Dump();
```

output:

```
AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public, Serializable, BeforeFieldInit
AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public, SequentialLayout, Sealed, Serializable, BeforeFieldInit
AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public, ClassSemanticsMask, Abstract
```

Answer (score 0):

well if you look at MSDN is says

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isansiclass%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> Property Value
>
> Type: System.Boolean
>
> true if the string format attribute AnsiClass is selected for the Type; otherwise, false.
>
> Implements
> _Type.IsAnsiClass

which is rather less than useful but if you look at the the `StringFormatMask` of the `TypeAttributes` Enumeration, you will see it has the possible values of `{AnsiClass,UnicodeClass,AutoClass,CustomFormatClass}`

so basically it informs the compiler how to interpret the strings within the class as ANSI or Unicode, which as far as i'm aware has no impact on c# and vb but can lead to all sorts of issues if your using c++ classes

see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2995/The-Complete-Guide-to-C-Strings-Part-I-Win-Chara