# Clipboard.Set comaprision

Tags: c#, wpf

When trying to copy to the clipboard, what is the difference between

```
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, "");
```

and

```
Clipboard.SetText("");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SetText` is simply a convenience method for `SetData`, only with `SetText` using [`UnicodeText` versus yours, which is `ANSI`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textdataformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[From source](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/wpf/src/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/clipboard@cs/1471291/clipboard@cs):

```
    public static void SetText(string text)
    { 
        ....
        SetText(text, TextDataFormat.UnicodeText); //<------------
    }

    public static void SetText(string text, TextDataFormat format) 
    {
        ....
        SetDataInternal(DataFormats.ConvertToDataFormats(format), text);
    }

    public static void SetData(string format, object data) 
    {
        ....
        SetDataInternal(format, data);
    }
```

So, both use `SetDataInternal`

Answer (score 2):

The format `Text` that you use does not specify that it's Unicode. [As we can see in the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Clipboard.cs,fe593108ebd432e0), `SetText` calls `SetDataInternal(DataFormats.UnicodeText, data)` while your second example calls `SetDataInternal(DataFormats.Text, data`).

The `DataFormats.Text` specifies ANSI encoding. It basically means speciál characters get replaced by some `?` or similar. Read more about this format in this other question/answer: [What is ANSI format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format)

Comment: That would explain why I am not getting certain characters back :)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says what [`Clipboard.SetText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597043%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does:

> Stores [UnicodeText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dataformats.unicodetext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) data on the Clipboard.

That suggests that `Clipboard.SetText("")` is equivalent to `Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText, "");`

So, to answer your question, `Clipboard.SetText("")` puts an empty **unicode** text string into the clipboard, while `Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, "");` stores there an empty **ANSI** text string.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between setting Text and Data of Text really there are none.
When setting the clipboard, for example you could set the clipboard to a Folder so the user could copy and paste files, or text. So setting the data type for the clip board is required, but if you use the preset function SetText it was created to save the programmer time by not having to do so.

this code `Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, "");` is the same as `Clipboard.SetText("");` except inside the function `SetText(String text)` it will set the data format for you, the code inside SetText (after decompilation) is

```
public static void SetText(string text, TextDataFormat format)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
   {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("text");
   }
   if (!System.Windows.Forms.ClientUtils.IsEnumValid(format, (int) format, 0, 4))
   {
      throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("format", (int) format, typeof(TextDataFormat));
   }
   System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject data = new DataObject();
   data.SetData(ConvertToDataFormats(format), false, text);
   SetDataObject(data, true);
}
```