# read files with different encoding format using sys.stdin in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, gbk

I have many files which are encoded with UTF-8 or GBK. My system encoding is UTF-8 (`LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8`), so I can read files encoded with UTF-8 easily. But I must read file encoding with GBK as well. I'm following [Python 3: How to specify stdin encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549332/python-3-how-to-specify-stdin-encoding) here:

```
import sys 
import io
input_stream = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdin.buffer, encoding='gbk')
for line in input_stream:
    print(line)
```

My question is how can I read all the files (both GBK and UTF-8) safely from  `sys.stdin`. Or can you give me some better solution?

To slightly expand on this question, I want to handle files like this:

```
cat *.in | python3 handler.py
```

`*.in` returns many files encoded with either UTF-8 or GBK.

If I use the following code in `handler.py`

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    ...some code
```

it will throw an error as soon as it tries to process a GBK file:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

On the other hand, if I use code like this:

```
input_stream = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdin.buffer, encoding='gbk')
for line in input_stream:
    ...some code
```

it will throw an error on any UTF-8 file:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 25: illegal multibyte sequence
```

I want to find a safe way to handle both types of files (UTF-8 and GBK) within my script.

Comment: You need to open each file first as a stream of bytes, snoop inside it to work out the encoding for yourself, then close it and reopen it with the appropriate encoding.

Comment: Using `cat *.in` for files with different encoding is problematic, because it produces a single stream with inconsistent encoding, which is a nightmare to deal with. You should redesign your script to accept a list of file names, then the codec guessing can be done on a per-file basis, without the need to detect the points where the encoding changes.

Comment: If you have a static set of files, consider re-encoding the GBK files with UTF-8.

Comment: @YaozongLi your clarification was perfect! Well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the input as raw bytes, and then examine the input to decide what to *actually* decode it into.

See also [Reading binary data from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850893/reading-binary-data-from-stdin)

Assuming you can read entire lines at a time (i.e. the encoding for an entire line can be expected to be consistent), I'd try to decode as utf-8, then fall back to gbk.

```
for raw_line in input_stream:
    try:
        line = raw_line.decode('utf-8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        line = raw_line.decode('gbk')
    # ...
```