# Comma separate input parameters?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a script `foo.cmd`:

```
echo %1 %2
```

In PowerShell I run:

```
foo.cmd "a,b" "c"
```

Expected output: `a,b c`
Actual output: `a b`

Why?

Comment: This is an example of strange behavior introduced by PowerShell (there is another example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313953/findstr-always-fails-to-find-hash-string-in-text-file)). In other words: this would work as expected in a pure Batch file.

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes are removed after PowerShell parsed the command line and passes it to CMD for execution, so CMD actually sees a statement

```
foo.cmd a,b c
```

Since the comma is one of CMD's [delimiter characters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html#delimiters) that statement is equivalent to

```
foo.cmd a b c
```

To avoid this behavior you need to ensure that the double quotes are preserved when passing the arguments to CMD. There are several ways to achieve this. For instance, you could put the double quoted arguments in single qoutes:

```
foo.cmd '"a,b"' "c"
```

and change the positional parameters in the batch script to `%~1`, `%~2` so that CMD removes the double quotes from the arguments.

If you have PowerShell v3 or newer you can use the ["magic parameter"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/06/13/new-v3-language-features/) `--%` to avoid the nested quotes:

```
foo.cmd --% "a,b" "c"
```

You still need `%~1` and `%~2` in the batch script, though.

Comment: Can you explain the "PowerShell parsed the command line and passes it to CMD for execution" part? What is the exactly underlying mechanism that sees a cmd be spun up and the parsed command passed to it from PowerShell?

Comment: What is there to explain? PowerShell runs batch scripts with the handler that is configured for batch scripts (usually CMD). And it parses every statement, otherwise it wouldn't be able to expand variables, expressions, etc.

Comment: So does PowerShell actually starts a new cmd and the cmd runs "foo.cmd a,b c"?