# Alternative to grep for isolating specific text in Windows command line

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, cmd

My network changes rather dynamically and unfortunately I am forced to run Windows.

This script works because I have installed GNU tools for Windows and can use grep.

I would like to be able to run this script on any windows machine without having to install anything (grep etc). I used findstr in this at first but could not get it to show only what matches the regex string.

```
@echo off

set %IPLIST% = nul
Echo.
Echo "Pinging all local Gateways"
    ipconfig | findstr /i "Gateway" | grep -o "[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*" > %IPLIST%

For /F "Usebackq Delims=" %%# in ("%IPLIST%") 
do (
    Echo+
    Echo [+] Pinging: %%#

Ping -n 1 "%%#" 1>nul && (
    Echo     [OK]) || (
    Echo     [FAILED])
)

Echo.
Echo.

Echo "now testing your internet connection"
Echo .
Echo ...

if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    echo ....you're all good bro.
) else (
    ping -n 3 "8.8.8.8" | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms"
    if %errorlevel% == 1 (
echo ....all is lost
)
)
Echo.
```

Comment: Convert it to PowerShell.  Should be on all Windows machines XP and later.

Comment: +1 to use PowerShell instead of suffering with cmd.exe shell scripting (batch). PowerShell has `Select-String` which returns MatchInfo objects, and you can easily extract substrings.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: Beware of the _unrequested_ suggestions on using PowerShell instead Batch! PowerShell may introduce errors not present in the original Batch code, like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313953/findstr-always-fails-to-find-hash-string-in-text-file) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591034/comma-separate-input-parameters) examples, or be a worst solution than the Batch file one, like in [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35637893/replace-multiple-lines-in-powershell) where the OP said: _"It worked, and better than powershell :)"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of problems with the script.

```
set %IPLIST% = nul
```

This would yield a syntax error because `iplist` is likely undefined, and you are attempting to set the variable `contents of iplist` to "nul"

The resolution of this would be

```
set  = nul
```

Further, spaces on either side of the `=` are included in the variable/value set, so removing the `%`s would set the value of iplist<kbd>Space</kbd> to <kbd>Space</kbd>nul

Had `iplist` indeed been set up to `nul` then your `ipconfig` command would have simply dumped its eventual output into the bit-bucket as it would have been sent to `nul`.

```
For /F "Usebackq Delims=" %%# in ("%IPLIST%")
```

The `do (` must be on the same physical line as the "for"

```
<opinion>Using non-alphas as metavariables is not a good idea as it is not officially supported <\opinion>

if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    echo ....you're all good bro.
) else (
    ping -n 3 "8.8.8.8" | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms"
    if %errorlevel% == 1 (
echo ....all is lost
)
)
```

Because of the `delayed expansion trap` (all `%var%` in a block (parenthesised sequence of statements) are replaced by their value at **parse-time**) the innermost `%errorlevel%` here would be replaced by whatever `errorlevel` was set to when the outermost `if` was encountered. To interpret the `ping` output, you'd need to either invoke `delayedexpansion` (many, many SO items on this subject) or use the old original `if errorlevel n...` construct, where the `if` condition is true if the current `errorlevel` is `n` or greater than `n`.

So - reconstructing using batch features,

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

Echo.
Echo "Pinging all local Gateways"
For /F "tokens=2 Delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig ^| findstr /i "Gateway"') DO IF "%%a" neq " " (
    Echo+
    Echo [+] Pinging: %%a

Ping -n 1 %%a 1>nul && (
    Echo     [OK]) || (
    Echo     [FAILED])
)

Echo.
Echo.

Echo "now testing your internet connection"
Echo .
Echo ...

if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    echo ....you're all good bro.
) else (
    ping -n 3 "8.8.8.8" | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms"
    if ERRORLEVEL 1 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 2 (
echo ....all is lost
)
)
Echo.
GOTO :EOF
```

The 'for /f`tokenises the output of the command in single-quotes using`:`as a delimiter and picking the second token to apply to`%%a`.

The `|` needs to be escaped by a caret to tell `cmd` that it is part of the command to be executed, not part of the `for`.

The `for` processes the output of `ipconfig...` so `%%a` has the form Spacexxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

On my machine,  `xxx...` was missing on one line, so I filtered out the single-space response.

Pinging `%%a` *without the quotes* adds an extra space into the `ping` line, which is harmless. With the quotes, it didn't like it.

Then the appendix...

I'm not sure what you're really attempting here. Perhaps it was a frustrated debug attempt.

`errorlevel` will be set to whatever the `last` ping result was. This is logically unpredictable.

I've shown a correct method of interpreting the `findstr` errorlevel result. I'm not sure that your regex is correct here...but the `all is lost` message would only be shown if `findstr` sets errorlevel to 1.

Comment: Thanks, 
I had fixed some of those issues but with your input I have what I need
Thank you