# Failed to parse template: Error parsing JSON: invalid character 'ÿ' looking for beginning of value

Tags: json, parsing, powershell-4.0, packer

> Failed to parse template: Error parsing JSON: invalid character 'Ã¿' looking for beginning of value

Im getting this error, when I use

```bsh
$Parsed_json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 999 -Compress |
    Out-File $nameOfJsonFile -Force
```

and this:

> Failed to parse template: Error parsing JSON: invalid character 'ÿ' looking for beginning of value

when using

```bsh
$Parsed_json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 999 | Out-File $nameOfJsonFile -Force
```

The JSON online validator approves of my JSON.

My research so far about this topic, is that the Unicode characters that prints themselves when you use `Out-File`, is creating this issue. The encoding of my JSON file is ASCII, any help regarding this issue, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: When/where exactly are you getting this error? When converting `$Parsed_json`? When writing the file? Or when reading the file that you wrote? In case of the latter: show the code that actually throws the error. And did you try `Set-Content` (which defaults to ASCII output) or `Out-File -Encoding Ascii` (to override the default UTF-8 encoding)?

Comment: Using Out-file with -3ncoding parameter solves the issue. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this is an encoding problem. The resolution is to create the output file using ASCII encoding (well, actually it's an [ANSI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701882/1630171) encoding, but since the parameter argument is named `Ascii` let's stick with that for simplicity's sake), e.g. like this:

```
$Parsed_json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 999 -Compress |
    Out-File $nameOfJsonFile -Encoding Ascii -Force
```

or like this (`Set-Content` uses ASCII encoding by default):

```
$Parsed_json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 999 -Compress |
    Set-Content $nameOfJsonFile -Force
```

Comment: Works just fine, Thank Ansgar Wiechers