# Read from file and write to file 'Ł' character with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, polish

I have an ansi file with 'Ł' character I would like to read this character and save it to another file with the same encoding(to get 'Ł' character).

```
const fs = require('fs');
var content = fs.readFileSync('input.txt',null); //Ł
fs.writeFileSync('output.txt',content,null); //Ł how to get this?
```

How to do this with nodejs?

Update: I checked the input file:

file -i

> text/plain charset=uknown-8bit

file -r

> Non-ISO extended-ASCII, text with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators

Can I save the file with such details?

Comment: Define "ansi file" -- what **specific** encoding is the file using? When I try to save a file from Notepad with the "ANSI" option in the drop-down box (which I believe uses Windows-1252), it fails to save correctly, which makes me wonder if it has a mapping in that encoding...

Comment: I open the file with notepad++, it says ANSI.

Comment: That code should work (regardless of encoding). When you don't give `readFile`/`readFileSync` an encoding, it reads a raw buffer (no conversion of data). When you give `writeFile`/`writeFileSync` a buffer, it doesn't use an encoding, it just writes the data.

Comment: ^^ Verified, it happily copies files bit-for-bit.

Comment: Yes, it actually works, I just need to figure out how to concatenate this character with the rest of my string and save it to file properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved what I wanted by creating binary strings out of buffer with the problematic characters:

```
const fs = require('fs');
function getChar(charId) {
    let characters = { AA:165, //Ą
         EE:202, //Ę
         CC:198, //Ć
         LL:163, //Ł
         SS:140, //Ś
         OO:211, //Ó
         ZZ:175, //Ż
         ZZZ:143, //Ź
         aa:185, //ą
         ee:234, //ę
         cc:230, //ć
         ll:179, //ł
         ss:156, //ś
         oo:243, //ó
         zz:191, //ź
         zzz:159 //ź
    };
    let buf = new Buffer({
        type:'Buffer',
        data:[ characters[charId] ],
        encoding:'ISO-8859-2'
    });
    return buf.toString('binary')
}
fs.writeFileSync('output.txt',getChar('LL')+" test",'ascii'); //'Ł test'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely this is a utf-8 encoded file, rather than an "ansi" one. That 'Ł' character is not representable on the [ansi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format) encoding. Check with the `file` command on unix-es what sort of encoding it has and proceed from there.

Comment: As it stands, this is a *comment* (a useful one), not an answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder true, but there's not that much to go on in the question. Hoping they would update the question so I can expand on the answer.

Comment: I updated the question after checking the file with `file` command.