# How to handle UTF-8 encoded source when compiling on Windows?

Tags: windows, encoding

I'm currently writing a small C program, using MinGW's gcc to compile it on Windows. I'm also hosting it on GitHub (and using GitHub Desktop for Windows). GitHub, however, appears to enforce UTF-8 encoding in the files and the Windows Terminal have trouble dealing with UTF-8.

After some searching I found a few solutions, but they require manual, end-user style solutions, which I want to avoid (I'm not planning on distributing it or anything, but I wonder what I would do if I was).

What currently works is changing the encoding to ANSI and manually fixing everything before compilation, but I would rather avoid having to do that every damn time I want to work on Windows.

So the question is: How to handle UTF-8 encoded source when compiling on Windows?

---

Here's some sample output:

[[image: Screenshot]]

- Left: Source Code encoded in UTF-8 (displayed wrong).
- Right: Source code encoded in ANSI (displayed right).

Compilation process is exactly the same, only difference is the actual source-code encoding.

Comment: I hope I didn't left any relevant information out, but if I did please ask!

Comment: Doesn't gcc handle that automatically?

Comment: GCC handles it fine, but the problem appears to be caused by Windows Terminal. Apparently it only works with the Lucida Console font, but I don't want to have to change the terminal font just so my program runs.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not opening any files! My source-code is encoded in UTF-8 and the compiled file isn't encoded correctly on Windows. When transcoding my source to ANSI everything works fine! -- However, pretty interesting to know fopen() handles encoding. Thanks!

Comment: So gcc compiles it ok in UTF-8 but the exe doesn't run? What actually goes wrong?

Comment: Does Windows have an equivalent of `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")` that you should call early on to change the stdio coding system from the C locale, as POSIX does?

Comment: @JeremyP [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/iIJcSG4.png). Left: Source Code encoded in UTF-8 (displayed wrong). Right: Source code encoded in ANSI (displayed right). Compilation process is exactly the same, only difference is the actual source-code encoding.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, locale.h is a standard library and calling setlocale() is needed for the program to work properly in the ANSI version. In the UTF-8 version setlocale() changes the displayed chars, but both are wrong.

Comment: You need to find an API function that will convert your UTF-8 strings into strings using the encoding that the user has set for his/her PC. I don't know what that is in C on Windows.

Comment: Wht do you mean with "encoded in ANSI"?

Comment: @Olaf [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/701920/7362590) explains better than I could.

Comment: Can you write a [mcve] (which would be little more than `puts("foo");` and the compile command) so we can see what you tried so far?

Comment: It does not. It is actually wrong. There is no "ANSI" encoding. There is just a whole zoo of encodings which are base on ASCII, using aditional 128 codes for various purposes. They are all very different. And none covers the full Unicode character set.

Comment: Hey guys, I managed to figure it out (and posted it as a reply)! Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused by the fact that the Windows Terminal have issues displaying UTF-8 encoded characters normally.

To solve the issue you need to tell the terminal to use the UTF-8 Code Page. You do **not need** to call setlocale() after changing the codepage, as this will probably mess things.

To tell Windows which codepage it should use to display output you can use the [SetConsoleOutputCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686036(v=vs.85).aspx) function passing the UTF-8 code (65001) as parameter (for more information check "[Code Page Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx)" from MSDN).

Here is a test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    UINT CODEPAGE_UTF8 = 65001;
    UINT CODEPAGE_ORIGINAL = GetConsoleOutputCP();

    printf("DEFAULT CODEPAGE, DEFAULT LOCALE: ¶\n");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    printf("DEFAULT CODEPAGE, SYSTEM LOCALE: ¶\n");

    SetConsoleOutputCP(CODEPAGE_UTF8);

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");
    printf("UTF-8 CODEPAGE, DEFAULT LOCALE: ¶\n");

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    printf("UTF-8 CODEPAGE, SYSTEM LOCALE: ¶\n");

    SetConsoleOutputCP(CODEPAGE_ORIGINAL);
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the program output, compiled with source code encoded in ANSI, UTF-8 without BOM (Byte Order Mark) and UTF-8 with BOM, respectively:

[[image: TEST OUTPUT]]

Caveat: Some info around the internet says this only works with certain fonts, notably Lucida Console. Also, this only works on Windows 2000 Professional and above. I don't think you will need to touch something older than that nowadays, though.

Comment: Thank you so much! `SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)` saved my day!