# UNICODE_STRING to ANSI_STRING conversion with RtlUnicodeStringToAnsiString

Tags: c++, unicode, kernel, driver

The documentation on [RtlUnicodeStringToAnsiString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648421(v=vs.85).aspx) is rather vague about its possible failures - by vague I mean it doesn't say anything about them.

I'm not exactly sure how/if it deals with different encodings, or if my understanding is so flawed that it doesn't even come into the equation, but let's assume input is [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) for argument's sake.

If all the characters are within the ASCII range then there is no problem, they can just get truncated and lose the high order byte - The first 128 Unicode code points are the ASCII characters and UTF-16 encodes U+0000 to U+D7FF as numerically equal to the code points.[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)[[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)

Note: [UNICODE_STRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380518(v=vs.85).aspx) has a WCHAR* Buffer, and [ANSI_STRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540605(v=vs.85).aspx) a CHAR* Buffer, as may be expected.

[Skipping over 129-255 and locales/codepages]

What happens with characters above 255? There is an [RtlUnicodeToUTF8N](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562992(v=vs.85).aspx) function so it's safe to assume it doesn't convert to UTF-8.

How about code points outside [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) (surrogate pairs and whatnot)?

I saw a function that does something like the code below:

```
char *pTarget = reinterpret_cast<char*>(char_str);
const WCHAR  *pSource = reinterpret_cast<const WCHAR*>(wchar_str);

for ( long i = 0; i < targetMaxSizeInBytes; i++ )
{
    *pTarget = static_cast<char>(*pSource);

    if (L'\0' == *pSource)
        break;

    pTarget++;
    pSource++;
}
```

This would cause problems with any non-ASCII characters, correct?

**Update:**

From RbMm's answer:

> [RtlUnicodeStringToAnsiString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562969(v=vs.85).aspx) is shell over [RtlUnicodeToMultiByteN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553261(v=vs.85).aspx) routine

I get a little more information:

> Like **RtlUnicodeToMultiByteSize**, **RtlUnicodeToMultiByteN** supports only precomposed Unicode characters that are mapped to the current system ANSI code page installed at system boot.

[WideCharToMultiByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx) has an option to be notified if a default character is used in the conversion for a character that cannot be represented in the specified code page:

> lpUsedDefaultChar [out, optional]
>
> Pointer to a flag that indicates if the function has used a default character in the conversion. The flag is set to **TRUE** if one or more characters in the source string cannot be represented in the specified code page. Otherwise, the flag is set to **FALSE**. This parameter can be set to **NULL**.

However, it seems RtlUnicodeToMultiByteN, and therefore RtlUnicodeStringToAnsiString, simply don't support characters outside the current code page?

I tried a few characters and got seemingly random conversions (see below) - more importantly, I got **STATUS_SUCCESS** returned.

```
U+03A3 Σ -> 0n83 'S'
U+03A4 Τ -> 0n63 '?'
U+03A5 Υ -> 0n63 '?'
U+03A6 Φ -> 0n70 'F'
```

Comment: ANSI is not ASCII have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format and note that _"The translation is done with respect to the current system locale information."_

Comment: @RichardCritten I know, but ANSI is always the same as ASCII for the first 128 characters, so I "[skipped] over 129-255 and locales/codepages".

Answer (score 1):

[`RtlUnicodeStringToAnsiString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562969(v=vs.85).aspx) is shell over [`RtlUnicodeToMultiByteN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553261(v=vs.85).aspx) routine

> The **RtlUnicodeToMultiByteN** routine translates the specified Unicode
>   string into a new character string, using the current system **ANSI
>   code page (ACP)**. The translated string is not necessarily from a
>   multibyte character set.

so any of this routine have the same conversion as [`WideCharToMultiByte`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx) with **CP_ACP**

also exist next routines:

[`RtlUnicodeStringToOemString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553255(v=vs.85).aspx) - shell over [`RtlUnicodeToOemN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553272(v=vs.85).aspx) routine

> The **RtlUnicodeToOemN** routine translates a given Unicode string to
>   an OEM string, using the current system **OEM code page**.

so this routines have the same conversion as [`WideCharToMultiByte`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx) with **CP_OEMCP**

for **UTF-8** convertions exist [`RtlUnicodeToUTF8N`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562992(v=vs.85).aspx) (*converts a Unicode string to a UTF-8 string*) and [`RtlUTF8ToUnicodeN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563018(v=vs.85).aspx) (*converts a UTF-8 string to a Unicode string.* )

for custom code page you can use undocumented api

```
NTSYSAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
RtlCustomCPToUnicodeN(
    _In_ PCPTABLEINFO CustomCP,
    _Out_writes_bytes_to_(MaxBytesInUnicodeString, *BytesInUnicodeString) PWCH UnicodeString,
    _In_ ULONG MaxBytesInUnicodeString,
    _Out_opt_ PULONG BytesInUnicodeString,
    _In_reads_bytes_(BytesInCustomCPString) PCH CustomCPString,
    _In_ ULONG BytesInCustomCPString
    );
```

here key point in initialize [`CPTABLEINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt791523(v=vs.85).aspx), so you can use any *USHORT  CodePage;* here

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I have used [WideCharToMultiByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/dd374130) before to convert from UTF-16 (wchar_t*) and UTF-8 (char*), passing the `CP_UTF8` as the code page.

Edit: I just noted the kernel tag. The function I quoted is in user mode (kernel32.dll), so probably not useful for kernel mode code. :(

Comment: Yes this is running in kernel-mode drivers. I'm also concerned with understanding existing code. Thanks for the tip though :)

Comment: No problem! I agree that the documentation of error conditions for that function are really vague. It would make sense that any UTF-16 chars above 0x007f would map to equivalents in the loaded ANSI codepage, when possible. Not sure if the UTF-16 chars (2 or 4-byte chars) that can't be mapped would be written as '?' like some Win32 functions do.

Comment: By written as '?' you mean actually putting U+003F in place of whatever 2 or 4-byte character was there? About the only thing the documentation says is that if the return code isn't STATUS_SUCCESS then "no storage was allocated and no conversion was done", so I would hope it doesn't change characters and still return STATUS_SUCCESS.

Comment: You're probably right that it doesn't do the conversion if it doesn't know what to do. Who knows... ;-)