# Invalid character in csv .writerow

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, exception

I'm using Python 3.7 to write a .csv file with the build in lib csv.
The error occurs if input contains the Unicode character "White bullet"
https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%E2%97%A6:

> ◦

Code:

```
with open(filename, 'w', newline='', encoding='ansi') as csvfile:
            filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

filewriter.writerow(['H', debitor, None, customer_name, notes, setup.HQ])
```

Error:
`'mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0--1: invalid character`

Is this a bug or is there some limitation I'm not aware of?

Comment: Why not change the encoding to `'utf-8'` then? ANSI is for Latin alphabets only.

Comment: I'm loading the csv file into SAP on Windows, and Danish letters æ, ø and å only shown correctly if I encode as ANSI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANSI encoding (read about it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/701920/9225671) or on this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)) does NOT have the character "white bullet", so there is simply no way to represent that character with an ANSI encoding.

You have three option:

1. Change the encoding to something that supports that specific char, for example `utf-8` or some other encoding.
2. Skip/remove that char.
3. Replace that char with something else that is valid in ANSI encoding.