# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 24: invalid start byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, kaggle

I am trying to load the "Crimes in Boston" database on Kaggle notebook,
(https://www.kaggle.com/AnalyzeBoston/crimes-in-boston)
by the way, the most updated version of this data can be found here:
(https://data.boston.gov/dataset/crime-incident-reports-august-2015-to-date-source-new-system/resource/12cb3883-56f5-47de-afa5-3b1cf61b257b)
, and when I want to read the data using Pandas, I get this error:

```
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 24: invalid start byte
```

Here is how I try to load the data into the kernel:

```
my_filepath = '../input/crimes-in-boston/crime.csv'
my_data = pd.read_csv(my_filepath , encoding = 'utf8')
```

Comment: Please share the data of your csv file.

Comment: Then it is not an UTF-8 file. You did not link to it, and I don't want to search for it, but... try another encoding.

Comment: @SagarGuptaFTW https://www.kaggle.com/AnalyzeBoston/crimes-in-boston

Comment: @amadan Sorry for forgetting to put the link. here is the link to the data : https://www.kaggle.com/AnalyzeBoston/crimes-in-boston

Comment: @SafaGharavi Unable to download. Asking for login.

Comment: @SagarGuptaFTW what about this?
https://data.boston.gov/dataset/crime-incident-reports-august-2015-to-date-source-new-system/resource/12cb3883-56f5-47de-afa5-3b1cf61b257b

Comment: @SafaGharavi What solved your question?

Comment: @SafaGharavi With providing a different dataset than your original question, you have actually tampered with the original question, and basically hacked your own question. This isn't appreciated.

Comment: @SafaGharavi can you please mark the correct answer as the "real answer"? What is the difference between your problem, the current answer and my answer? Why you don´t mark the real answer from Tankred as the answer?

Comment: @SagarGuptaFTW I mentioned that I am working on Kaggle kernels environment and trying to read the csv file there. But it seems that (as people commenting here claim so, I haven't tested it yet) the problem is because of the Kaggle's data version.

Comment: @SafaGharavi Just imagine a new user comes to this page. They will be completely baffled by what's going on here. Question is tampered, not making much sense anymore. You should infact delete the question altogether, I would say, because itsn't adding any value to StackOverflow wiki. And please ask questions in a better way in the future.

Comment: @SagarGuptaFTW Man, I'm just a beginner trying to learn something here, not hacking my own question or anything else.

Comment: @SafaGharavi We are all learners here. But understand that StackOverflow is not a question-answer site, it's a wiki. It should contain useful resources for all users (including future visitors). This question isn't a good quality question anymore, so should be deleted.

Comment: @SagarGuptaFTW StackOverflow doesn't let me delete my question because people have commented on it so far.

Answer (score 3):

I could read the file using `encoding='ansi'`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/701920/5665958) for some info on ANSI encoding.

My solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('crime.csv', encoding='ansi')
```

**Update**: If you are getting the error `LookupError: unknown encoding: ansi` use `encoding='cp1252'`.

Comment: it didn't work for me: 
```
LookupError: unknown encoding: ansi

Comment: Strange. How about `encoding='cp1252'`? This is the official name for that encoding.

Comment: @SafaGharavi This should be the answer.