# How to set encoding as 'ANSI' using Python?

Tags: python, ansi

I am using Python 3.7.4 version. I want to set the encoding as 'ANSI' at the time of reading a text file and also writing a text file.

I another case I read a file by providing 'utf-8' ( please find code snippet below ) as encoding but in case of 'ANSI' I am not finding any value to provide as encoding.

code snippet :

```
content = open(fullfile , encoding='utf-8').readlines()
```

What should be done to set encoding as 'ANSI' in Python ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ANSI is not actually an encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/701920/7506861), you probably mean Windows-1252, which Python supports as `'cp1252'`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no "ANSI"-encoding. "ANSI" means *"whatever the default single-byte encoding happens to be on your machine"* – the term "ANSI" is inherently ambiguous. This means you must specify an *actual* encoding when reading the file.

For Windows machines in the Western Europe region, "ANSI" typically refers to Windows-1252. Other regions differ, but also your machine configuration might be different.

Python refers to Windows-1252 as `cp1252`. If that really is the encoding your file is in depends on the file itself, and can only be found out by looking at it.

Often text editors (not Notepad, *real* text editors) have an option to interpret a file in various encodings. Pick the one that makes the data look right (pay attention to accented characters) and then find out Python's name for it.

Comment: Thanks for details explanation

Answer (score 2):

Try one of the ANSI encodings:

```
encoding='cp1252'
```

For further information, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format)