# Save file with ANSI encoding in VS Code

Tags: encoding, visual-studio-code

I have a text file that needs to be in ANSI mode. It specifies only that: ANSI. Notepad++ has an option to convert to ANSI and that does the trick.

In VS Code I don't find this encoding option. So I read up on it and it looks like ANSI doesn't really exist and should actually be called Windows-1252.

However, there's a difference between Notepad++'s ANSI encoding and VS Code's Windows-1252. It picks different codepoints for characters such as an accented uppercase e (É), as is evident from the document.

When I let VS Code guess the encoding of the document converted to ANSI by Notepad++, however, it still guesses Windows-1252.

So the questions are:

- Is there something like pure ANSI?
- How can VS Code convert to it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out the [upcoming VSCode 1.48 (July 2020) browser support](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/63a888d79159d1e360f00a8fea69f6e67feb5308/release-notes/v1_48.md#browser-support).

It also solves [issue 33720](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/33720), where you had to force encoding for the full project before with, for instance:

```
"files.encoding": "utf8",
"files.autoGuessEncoding": false
```

Now you can set the encoding file by file:

> ### Text file encoding support
>
> All of the text file encodings of the desktop version of VSCode are now supported for web as well.

[image: https://im4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-af94752f0c33.gif]

As you can see, the encoding list includes [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1), which is the [closest norm of what "ANSI encoding" could represent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/702023/6309).
The [Windows codepage 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) was created based on ISO 8859-1 but is not completely equal.
It differs from the IANA's ISO-8859-1 by using displayable characters rather than control characters in the 80 to 9F (hex) range

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Details):

> Historically, the phrase "ANSI Code Page" was used in Windows to refer to non-DOS encodings; the intention was that most of these would be ANSI standards such as ISO-8859-1.
>
> Even though Windows-1252 was the first and by far most popular code page named so in Microsoft Windows parlance, the code page has never been an ANSI standard.
>
> Microsoft explains, "The term ANSI as used to signify Windows code pages is a historical reference, but is nowadays a misnomer that continues to persist in the Windows community."