# ANSI encoding in python

Tags: python, encode

On Windows i can do like this:

```
>>> "\x98".encode("ANSI")
b'\x98'
```

On Linux it throws an error:

```
>>> "\x98".encode("ANSI")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
LookupError: unknown encoding: ANSI
```

How can i get `b"\x98"` from `"\x98"` on linux?
`CPXXXX` encodings don't work for me, because \x98 doesnt exist

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. It definitely depends on more than just whether you are using "Windows" or "Linux".

Comment: Python said ["Encode the operand according to the ANSI codepage (CP_ACP)."](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/codecs.html?highlight=ansi). and Microsoft said CP_ACP is [The system default Windows ANSI code page.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte). It seems that CP_ACP is locale-dependent.

Comment: docs.python.org says that ANSI is windows only (CP_ACP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding [this definition of ANSI encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/701920):

> ANSI encoding is a slightly generic term used to refer to the standard code page on a system, usually Windows. It is more properly referred to as Windows-1252 on Western/U.S. systems.

You can try:

```
"\x98".encode("cp1252")
```

But, Python doesn’t allow it so, you can use ISO Latin1 instead:

```
"\x98".encode("iso_8859_1")
# b'\x98'
```

Comment: ```UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x98' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>```

Comment: This is exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're expecting this to do.  U+0098 is an unprintable character.  You can try `bytes([ord("\x98")])` to do a raw translation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
def get_ansi_cp():
    import codecs
    import locale
    return codecs.lookup(locale.getpreferredencoding()).name
```

Which at my machine returns `cp1252`.