# How can I print extended ASCII characters in C?

Tags: c, printf, ascii, non-ascii-characters

How can I print for example "¶"?

I need to print some ASCII extended characters but obviously `printf("¶");` dosen't work. Some other posts have taken me to this [webpage](https://theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/letter-a-grave-accent-lowercase-ascii-code-133.html) but I don't know yet if there is any way to do it.

I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be aware that your editor might save your source code as UTF-8, which means "extended" characters like that won't be what you expect.

Comment: More importantly, what character encodings are you using a) in your source code and b) in the terminal where you run this program?

Comment: Also what terminal or other tool (a text editor, for example) do you want to show the result in?

Comment: If you're absolutely sure about the encoding of the output terminal, you might be able to do `printf("\xf4")`

Comment: It is better to use unicode instead of extended ASCII, in my opinion

Comment: I use Eclipse and Visual Studio Code.

Comment: printf("\xf4") actually works. But how did you get that "\ xf4" is "¶"? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: You can find ascii code of "¶" in the webpage you mentioned in your question.  
It's 244. And `244` is `f4` in hexadecimal. You can print chars with hexadecimal ascii code by prefixing `\x`

Comment: @Ultim8_Clock ASCII is a 7-bit charset. ["Extended ASCII" or "ANSI" is a misnomer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701882/995714). The result completely depends on the charset and you won't get ¶ if the charset is set differently

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. It also depends on codepage of the terminal so it's best to learn Unicode. Most generic and safe way to deal with non-ascii chars.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows, try typing `chcp 65001` in cmd before you execute the program.
This will set terminal's codepage to Unicode, allowing programs to print unicode chars.
For example, if your .exe file is in `C:\Users\You\Desktop\test.exe`:

```
> cd C:\Users\You\Desktop
> chcp 65001
> test.exe
```

This will also allow you to print other Unicode chars such as ⑩.

Comment: Thanks, this works, there is any way to implement this in the code?

Comment: Add `system("chcp 65001" >null")` to your code.  
`system()` function executes given string in cmd, and `>null` suppresses output produced by chcp command.
(Active code page: 65001)  
Beware that this code will now produce error on other OS, since chcp is windows cmd command.

Comment: Hey hey I made a mistake! It's `nul` not `null`. `nul` discards all output, but using `null` will create new file named 'null' and write all input into it

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleoutputcp is the right way to change the code page in a program.