# Gettext failed to extract non-ASCII characters

Tags: windows, gettext, xgettext

In my source files I have string containing non-ASCII characters like

`sCursorFormat = TRANSLATE("Frequency (Hz): %s\nDegree (°): %s");`

But when I extract them they vanish like

```
msgid ""
"Frequency (Hz): %s\n"
"Degree (): %s"
msgstr ""
```

I have specified the encoding when extracting as

`xgettext --from-code=UTF-8`

I'm running under MS Windows and the source files are C++ (not that it should matter).

Comment: You are a member here for more than 9 years. What coding language is this? How can we reproduce the problem on our machines? This question is not well defined.

Answer (score 1):

The encoding of your source file is probably not UTF-8, but ANSI, which stands for whatever the encoding for [non-Unicode applications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701882/395718) is (probably code page 1252). If you would open the file in some hex editor you would see byte 0x80 standing for degree symbol. This byte is not a valid UTF-8 character. In UTF-8 encoding degree symbol is represented with two bytes 0xC2 0xB0. This is why the byte vanishes when using `--from-code=UTF-8`.

The solution for your problem is to use `--from-code=windows-1252`. OR, better yet, to save all source files as UTF-8, and then use `--from-code=UTF-8`.

Comment: --from-code=windows-1252 didn't appear to do any difference, but changing the encoding of the file to UTF-8 did. Thanks.