# How do I generate a CSV with ANSI encoding using Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Currently I'm generating a CSV with UTF-8 encoding from my administrate ui. But swedish letters "åäö" is not shown correctly in excel or in the label printer programs (P-touch Editor 5.4 & Dymo Connect) I'm using.

After talking to their support I've been told the CSV needs to be ANSI encoded. How do I do that?

My code:

```
  def to_csv
    attributes = %w{full_name street_address postal_code city}

    CSV.generate(headers: true, col_sep: ",") do |csv|
      csv << attributes

      orders.all.each do |order|
        csv << attributes.map{ |attr| order.address.send(attr) }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: There is no such thing as an "ANSI encoding". You need to ask them *which precise encoding* they need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `CSV` uses `Encoding.default_external` as encoding, most likely this is UTF-8.

In your case you have to override it, but first you need to know *which* ANSI encoding you actually need. ([What is ANSI format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format))

Most likely you can use Windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1.

Then you can set the external encoding of the CSV string like this:

```rb
CSV.generate(headers: true, col_sep: ",", encoding: Encoding::ISO_8859_1)
CSV.generate(headers: true, col_sep: ",", encoding: Encoding::WINDOWS_1252)
```

Strings work, too:

```rb
CSV.generate(headers: true, col_sep: ",", encoding: 'ISO-8859-1')
```