# VBA - Import bas module with special characters

Tags: excel, vba, git, github, unicode

I have implemented a automated import+version controlling for excel-modules (bas, frx and frm files), so the clients will always get the newest version of VBA scripts.

The solution is something like this:

1. A vba scripts (on Workbook_Open) checks the github repository if the version number is equal
2. If not, the script will now do following

- Download main.zip from github
- Extract the zip files
- Remove all existing modules
- Import all modules

But the problem is, when importing modules, somehow the special characters in bas/frm/frx files will not be kept, they will be encoded to something else like:

**- pensionSheet.Cells(26, 2).value = JsonObject("BÃ¸rnerente")**

It should be

**- pensionSheet.Cells(26, 2).value = JsonObject("Børnerente")**

Iam using this following function to import bas modules:

```
Function addBasFile(strPath As String)

Dim path As String
Dim objModule As Object

path = strPath & "\pb_integration-main\pensionBrokerExport.bas"
Set objModule = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import(path)
objModule.Name = "PensionBrokerExport"
Debug.Print ("PensionBrokerExport imported")

End Function
```

Any idea how i can keep special chars when importing modules to excel?

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the file encoding. The file on GitHub must be stored in UTF-8, but the VBA editor expects a file encoded with ANSI.

Comment: Thank you for heads up!
So what do you suggest here, can i somehow encode the file to ANSI before import to VBA?

Comment: You can use ADO (the 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects' Library) to read text encoded as UTF-8 into a String, then write it back to a new file encoded ANSI using either 'normal VBA' file methods or using the FileSystemObject (part of the 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' library)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the files downloaded from GitHub inside VS Code, Notepad++ or even Notepad you'll probably see at the bottom right corner that the file is encoded with `UTF-8`. That's a problem since the VBA editor expects the file to be encoded in the local "ANSI" encoding ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format)).

[image]

If you also see `LF` to the right of the file encoding, that means that the line endings are using Unix-style line endings (line feed) instead of Windows-style line endings (carriage return + line feed). That might cause issues as mentioned [here](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web/issues/24#issuecomment-50060052).

---

**To fix it**

Option 1: If you have full control over the Github repo, you could fix this easily by forcing the GitHub export-to-zip process to convert the line endings and text encoding for you. I explain it more in details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76548787/5958842), but the idea is to use a `.gitattributes` file. For example, here's what I use for VBA projects:

```bash
# Auto detect text files and perform LF normalization
* text=auto

# VBA extensions - Preseve CRLF in working directory
*.bas text eol=crlf working-tree-encoding=CP1252
*.cls text eol=crlf working-tree-encoding=CP1252
*.frm text eol=crlf working-tree-encoding=CP1252

# VBA extensions - Mark as binary
*.frx binary
```

Option 2: If you can't add a `.gitattributes` file or you don't want to, you could add the following to your code and run it on the files that need to be imported in VBA:

```
Sub ConvertGitHubFileForVbaImport(FilePath As String)

    'Read content of the file with utf-8 encoding
    Dim Content As String
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 2  ' Private Const adTypeText = 2
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile FilePath
        Content = .ReadText(-1)  ' Private Const adReadAll = -1
        .Close
    End With

    'Replace Unix-style line endings with Windows-style line endings (Need to check if that applies to your file)
    If InStr(Content, Chr$(13) & Chr$(10)) = 0 Then
        Content = Replace(Content, Chr$(10), Chr$(13) & Chr$(10))
    End If

    'Write file with default local ANSI encoding (generally Windows-1252 on Western/U.S. systems)
    Open FilePath For Output As #1
    Print #1, Content
    Close #1

End Sub
```