# What is "ANSI encoding" in NSIS?

Tags: windows, character-encoding, nsis, codepages

I have an application that is installed using [NSIS 3.x](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Main_Page). The installer stores a path in a file that will be later checked by the application. The path is written using the `FileWrite` function; the [documentation](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Reference/FileWrite) for `FileWrite` states the following:

> Writes an ANSI string to a file opened with FileOpen. If an error occurs writing, the error flag will be set.
>
> (If you are building a Unicode installer, the function makes the adequate conversion and writes an ANSI string)

I know that ANSI is a loosely defined term (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format), and its many answers). Is there a way to find out what is the actual encoding used by this NSIS function, so that I can later read the generated file properly from the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the Windows meaning of ANSI; it is the currently active/default  Windows codepage.

Before NSIS v3, NSIS was always "ANSI". It called [the "A" versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/unicode-in-the-windows-api?source=recommendations) of all API functions. Internally every string was just treated as bytes and no conversions were done. This is why `FileWrite` effectively wrote ANSI strings.

Unicode NSIS installers call `WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, ...)` to convert the Unicode string before calling `FileWrite`.

It should be considered safe and portable for ASCII but not other characters. Another machine might be configured with a different codepage as the default and not all Unicode characters can be converted correctly even on the same machine. The only exception would be Windows 10/11 configured to use UTF-8 as the default or if you [opt-in in the manifest](https://gist.github.com/sredna/e84d1ee00b00732c0dd43b590c9399c6).

If the application you are installing is also Unicode enabled then you should be using `FileWriteUTF16LE`.

You can also write Unicode .ini files:

```
FileOpen $0 $INSTDIR\cfg.ini a
FileWriteUTF16LE /BOM $0 "" ; Make sure it has a BOM
FileClose $0
WriteIniStr $INSTDIR\cfg.ini Paths App $InstDir
```

Comment: I don't have control over the installer; only over the application. So I cannot modify what the installer writes (which is why I need to figure out now to read it from the application).

Comment: For Windows 10/11, what would NSIS' FileWrite do??

Comment: Without the manifest bit, the same as everywhere else, the default "ANSI" codepage, whatever that is. With the manifest bit; UTF-8.

Comment: If you want to read the `WriteFile` in your application, use `MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, ...`