# How to convert ansii file to utf-8 encoded file through informatica workflow?

Tags: unix, informatica-powercenter

How to create UTF-8 encoded file through Infa PC workflow?
I have tried changing the settings to UTF-8 in file properties at workflow level and mapping level and also tried generating the file in ASCII and convert it to UTF-8 using iconv command in unix but no luck.
Command : **iconv -f ascii -t utf-8 f1.txt -o f1.utf8.txt**

Is there any way, can we generate UTF-8 encoded file directly through Informatica workflow? or
Can we change the ANSII encoded file to UTF-8 encoded file using UNIX script?

Answer (score 1):

From your command, you seem to mean ASCII, not "ANSII". If so, ASCII is a perfect subset of UTF-8. Every ASCII file is automatically a UTF-8 file, so there is no conversion necessary. This was a major goal in the design of UTF-8.

There is an encoding often referred to as ["ANSI"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/701920/97337) (with one "I"). If you really mean that one, then you'd use `-f ms-ansi` (or `-f cp1252`) in your `iconv` command.