# Ansi to UTF-8 using python causing error

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding

While I was trying to write a python program that converts Ansi to UTF-8, I found this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732996/how-can-i-convert-utf-8-to-ansi-in-python

which converts UTF-8 to Ansi.

I thought it will just work by reversing the order. So I coded

```
file_path_ansi = "input.txt"
file_path_utf8 = "output.txt"

#open and encode the original content
file_source = open(file_path_ansi, mode='r', encoding='latin-1', errors='ignore')
file_content = file_source.read()
file_source.close

#write 
file_target = open(file_path_utf8, mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
file_target.write(file_content)
file_target.close
```

But it causes error.

```
TypeError: file<> takes at most 3 arguments <4 given>
```

So I changed

```
file_source = open(file_path_ansi, mode='r', encoding='latin-1', errors='ignore')
```

to

```
file_source = open(file_path_ansi, mode='r', encoding='latin-1')
```

Then it causes another error:

```
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword arguemtn for this function
```

How should I fix my code to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to use the Python 3 version of the [`open()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), on Python 2. Between the major versions, I/O support was overhauled, supporting better encoding and decoding.

You can get the same new version in Python 2 as [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) instead.

I'd use the [`shutil.copyfileobj()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) to do the copying, so you don't have to read the whole file into memory:

```
import io
import shutil

with io.open(file_path_ansi, encoding='latin-1', errors='ignore') as source:
    with io.open(file_path_utf8, mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as target:
        shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
```

Be careful though; most people talking about ANSI refer to *one* of the [Windows codepages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page); you may really have a file in CP (codepage) 1252, which is *almost*, but not quite the same thing as [ISO-8859-1 (Latin 1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). If so, use `cp1252` instead of `latin-1` as the `encoding` parameter.

Comment: CP1251 is Cyrillic, it's CP1252 what's similar to ISO 8859-1.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  Thank you! But how can I know if my input.txt is written in cp1252 or Latin 1?

Comment: @user3123767: Latin-1 has control codes in the range 80-9F, while CP-1252 has some more characters there (see the [Wikipedia page on CP-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), look for the table rows `8_` and `9_`). If text decoded as cp1252 works and makes sense, then go for that. Few texts, if any, use the Latin-1 control codes anyway.

Comment: Please also import shutils and for sake of completeness - if it's the other way round errors are imho far more likely as UTF8 is a superset of ANSI. So if you try the other way round:

    with io.open(csv_file_path, encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as source:
        with io.open(csv_file_path_ansi, mode='w', encoding='cp1252', errors='ignore') as target:
            shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)

Comment: @Wolfgang: This answer specifically addresses the combination of codecs the question was using. It depends entirely on your actual data what codecs would make sense.