# How to use "encoding" argument in Python 2 for the open() function?

Tags: python, encoding, decode

Completely new to Python here... I hope this is not a stupid question.

Tried following the posts like the following:

1. [Is 'encoding is an invalid keyword' error inevitable in python 2.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049962/is-encoding-is-an-invalid-keyword-error-inevitable-in-python-2-x)
2. [Ansi to UTF-8 using python causing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24893173/ansi-to-utf-8-using-python-causing-error)

But couldn't really solve my problem.

So what I have here is a block of code in Python 3 format:

```
with open(fresh_file,'r', encoding='latin-1') as targ_f:
new_data_iter = csv.reader(targ_f,
                       delimiter = ',',
                       quotechar = '"')
new_data = [new_data for new_data in new_data_data_iter]
```

I have Python 2, so I want to change this code so that it becomes compatible with Python 2.

Here's what I've tried so far reading above posts:

```
with open(fresh_file,'r') as targ_f:
new_data_iter = csv.reader(targ_f.decode('latin-1'),
                       delimiter = ',',
                       quotechar = '"')
new_data = [new_data for new_data in new_data_data_iter]
```

but then I get an error code:

```
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

So I read upon the decode() documentation, it can only be done on string objects, and since my target_f is a file object, it cannot be applied. but then the new_data_iter is a cvs.reader type obj, so also cannot be applied. Now, I am not sure how to incorporate decode() into the python 2 code...

Comment: You can try using `from io import open` and `open` should work in python 2 as in python 3 here.

Comment: The `csv` module is not compatible with parsing Unicode input.

Comment: @fpietka thank you! it works now!!! :) wow that was a simple fix!