# UTF-8 encoded MS Access table

Tags: ms-access, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a MS Access table which is encoded in **UTF-8 charset** and the characters appear like this:

`ParticipaciÃ³ en comissiÃ³`

If I UTF-8 decode this text I get the correct text:

`Participació en comissió`

How can I utf-8 decode several Access table columns? I would like to end up with the same MS Access database but with the columns converted (utf-8 decoded). I cannot figure out an easy way to do this conversion.

Thanks in advance.

--

More clarifications:

*So how did you decode the text that you have in the question?* 
I simply put the sentence in an online utf-8 decoder but it crashes when there is a lot of text. FYI, the Access table comes from a MS SQL Server database with **Modern_Spanish_CI_AS** collation and **varchar (MAX)** data type field. Maybe is there a way to perform the conversion while exporting the table from the MS SQL Server?

Comment: So how did you decode the text that you have in the question?

Comment: This might provide a starting point, but you'll need to make the code work in the context of Access (which I think can be easily done): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28834528/convert-utf-8-string-to-iso-8859-1

Comment: How about using the nvarchar datatype? It's for a different encoding (UTF-16) but it is the datatype for the Unicode character set. That way string functions and collations would work, too, as would client APIs.

Comment: @TomBlodget Microsoft Access doesn't have an `nvarchar` data type. Just `short text` and `long text` for storing strings. And they are encoded using system encoding (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81154/how-do-i-determine-which-encoding-system-is-used-in-my-ms-access-database)

Comment: More clarifications added to the post. Thanks.

Comment: While searching for a solution I found this post that has a function decode utf-8 fields right from the MS SQL Server. I tested it and it works perfectly, althought quite slow. Hope this helps someone else with the same problem. Here it is: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168055/convert-text-value-in-sql-server-from-utf8-to-iso-8859-1)

Comment: @Mitteg: Please post this (and a short description how you used it) as answer. Thanks!

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Thanks for correcting my faulty research.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert text value in SQL Server from UTF8 to ISO 8859-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168055/convert-text-value-in-sql-server-from-utf8-to-iso-8859-1)  Even though the question originally referred only to MS Access, it is later revealed that the table actually resides on SQL Server and the question was already answered in full.  The MS Access label and extra wording don't really add anything to the question.

Answer (score 0):

While searching for a solution I found this post that has a function to decode utf-8 fields right from the MS SQL Server. I tested it and it works perfectly, althought it is quite slow. Hope this helps someone else with the same problem.

- New query editor and copy&paste the function provided in this link:
  [Convert text value in SQL Server from UTF8 to ISO 8859-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168055/convert-text-value-in-sql-server-from-utf8-to-iso-8859-1)